# Do Tensorflow have documentation in VS Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

My goal is to use Tensorflow in Visual Studio Code. However, the documentation is non existant. I can import it but there is a warning when I hover the import statement

What I've did:

1. Install tensorflow on Mac Mini M1 with

```
%pip install tensorflow-macos
%pip install tensorflow-metal
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is addressed in this thread- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/56231

The solution that worked for me is by creating a symlink in `lib/pythonx.x/site-packages/tensorflow`

```
ln -s ../keras/api/_v2/keras/ keras
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

The issue is related to the directory structure of TensorFlow and Keras within the Python environment. It can happen when the location of the Keras (or any other module) that your code is trying to import does not match the paths used by the TensorFlow package.

## Solution

You can resolve this issue by creating a symbolic link (*symlink*) to resolve the import issues. The *symlink* effectively points from one location to another, allowing your code to find the required Keras modules within TensorFlow.

You can create a symlink by running cmd as admin and giving the following command:

```
mklink /D "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\keras" "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\api\_v2\keras"
```

`user_name` is the user name on windows. Type the python version accordingly.

Once the symlink is created, restart your IDE, the pylance issue for Keras modules within TensorFlow should be resolved.